Why doesn't Apache on Unbuntu 22.0.4 recognize index.html as the default
I am using Vulr.com for a LAMP instance on Ubuntu 22.0.4.
DirectoryIndex seems to be correctly configured (see below), but index.html is not recognized as the default document.
Works
https://website.com/resume/index.html
Doesn't work
https://website.com/resume/
I haven't yet touched any configuration. How can I solve this issue?
root@mine:/etc# grep -r "DirectoryIndex"
apache2/mods-available/dir.conf:    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
apache2/sites-available/http-le-ssl.conf:    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
apache2/sites-available/http.conf:    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
apache2/sites-available/https.conf:        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html


What do you get instead? Check if mod_dir is loaded, DirectoryIndex default is index.html even when not specified if mod_dir is loaded.

@DanielFerradal "File not found,"
